# Removing Seasonality

Tags: time-series, seasonality

Excuse me for the basic question; however I am having trouble removing seasonality from    [this data](https://www.dropbox.com/s/md8h2gfx9mrys77/ausq.xlsx?dl=0). I have been using Win X-13 with no luck so far (it doesn't appear to do much to remove the fluctuations). Can someone please advise on how best to proceed with removing the seasonality from this data?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes free software is worth what you pay for it. The 201 values represent a number of possible regime changes and the software you are using doesn't deal with that (common) activity.[image] . The different regimes in a data set cause significant analytical problems far above your tool' capabilities thus confusion reigns leading to your consternation. Simple methods/approaches work on simple problems !  Advanced time series software can often detect structural/regime change . A difference in model parameters was detected at 2009/1 yielding a suggestion about parameter transience.[image] . A reasonable model was developed containing a strong seasonal structure along with the identification of some unusual data points.[image].  [image] . The plot of the forecasts reflects the seasonal structure .[image] . In terms of a seasonally adjusted series , the model errors reflect the original series adjusted for the model parameters  thus [image] and the table of these values(errors) are shown here [image] and here [image] and finally [image]